# Increase Dimensionality of a xarray from coordinates

Tags: python-xarray

Say I have the following 2d-array

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> budgets = np.array([
       [np.nan, 450.],
       [500.  , 100.],
       [np.nan, 900.],
    ])
```

whose values are positioned like so

```
>>> coords = [
        ('name' , ['Jack_teen' , 'John_adult', 'John_teen']), # over rows
        ('hobby', ['books', 'bicyle']),                       # over columns
    ]
```

Using [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) I can create a 2d labeled array, doing

```
>>> import xarray as xr
>>> x = xr.DataArray(budgets, coords=coords)
```

Thus when John was a teenager, he did not like books, which is visible if one gets its budget at that time

```
>>> x.sel(name='John_teen', hobby='books')
<xarray.DataArray ()>
array(nan)
Coordinates:
    name     |S10 'John_teen'
    hobby    |S6 'books'
```

What has changed with age

```
>>> x.sel(name='John_adult', hobby='books')
<xarray.DataArray ()>
array(500.0)
Coordinates:
    name     |S10 'John_adult'
    hobby    |S6 'books'
```

---

My question:

How would you do to turn this 2dl-array into a 3dl-array which considers a new dimension called `age` (whose coordinates would thus be `['adult','teen'])` while simplifying the coordinates of the dimension `name`?

Note that `name`'s coordinates are ***always*** structured with a separating underscore, I mean as NAME_AGE. Of course the object with which you start to do this is `x`.

Are there xarray-builtin manners to do this ? Or at least what is the fastest/cheapest approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we eventually want a dimension `'name'`, I'll rename the current `'name'` to `'name_age'`:

```
In [5]: x = x.rename({'name': 'name_age'})
```

We can construct a `MultiIndex` directly from the coordinate values and assign this as a stacked `DataArray` coordinate:

```
In [6]: x.coords['name_age'] = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
   ...:     [tuple(s.split('_')) for s in x.coords['name_age'].values],
   ...:     names=['name', 'age'])

In [7]: x
Out[7]:
<xarray.DataArray (name_age: 3, hobby: 2)>
array([[  nan,  450.],
       [ 500.,  100.],
       [  nan,  900.]])
Coordinates:
  * name_age  (name_age) MultiIndex
  - name      (name_age) object 'Jack' 'John' 'John'
  - age       (name_age) object 'teen' 'adult' 'teen'
  * hobby     (hobby) |S6 'books' 'bicyle'
```

If you then unstack `'name_age'`, you'll get the 3-D `DataArray` you want:

```
In [8]: x.unstack('name_age')
Out[8]:
<xarray.DataArray (hobby: 2, name: 2, age: 2)>
array([[[  nan,   nan],
        [ 500.,   nan]],

       [[  nan,  450.],
        [ 100.,  900.]]])
Coordinates:
  * hobby    (hobby) |S6 'books' 'bicyle'
  * name     (name) object 'Jack' 'John'
  * age      (age) object 'adult' 'teen'
```

Comment: looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this dirty approach is what I am going to do, but this just ***cannot*** be the best solution.

First, let turn this 2dl-array into a dict formed over tuple keys.

```
dict_ = {}
for hobby in x['hobby'].data:
    for name_age in x['name'].data:
        name,age = name_age.split('_')
        dict_[(hobby, name, age,)] = x.sel(name=name_age, hobby=hobby).data
```

The space in which these values are located is formed over the following list of dimensions: `['hobby', 'name', 'age']`. Let assign it

```
>>> space = ['hobby', 'name', 'age']
```

Then, one can use the method `from_tuples` of [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)'s [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html) object to build the boolean-locating structure of our data

```
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(dict_.keys(), names=space)
```

And finally,

```
>>> hyper_x = pd.Series(dict_, index=index).to_xarray()
```

Thus

```
>>> hyper_x.sel(name='John', age='teen', hobby='books')
<xarray.DataArray ()>
array(nan)
Coordinates:
    hobby    |S5 'books'
    name     |S4 'John'
    age      |S4 'teen'
>>> hyper_x.sel(name='John', age='adult', hobby='books')
<xarray.DataArray ()>
array(500.0)
Coordinates:
    hobby    |S5 'books'
    name     |S4 'John'
    age      |S5 'adult'
```

---

The advantage of this approach is that it can be easily generalized to any number of dimensions, be it of `x` or `hyper_x`. And it can be used to decrease the dimensionality as well.